# Jasmine Test: Object doesn't support property or method

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I have just found about the Jasmine Framework, I am trying it out and though I should try writing a custom matcher, because it sounds extremely useful to be able to do. I did this:

```
describe('Hello World', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
        this.addMatchers({
            toBeDivisbleByTwo: function() {
                var result = {
                    pass: (this.actual % 2) === 0
                };
                if(result.pass) {
                    result.message = 'this is divisible by two';
                } else {
                    result.message = 'this is not divisible by two';
                }

                return result;
            }
        });
    });
});

describe('Hello world', function() {
    it('divisible by two', function() {
        expect(evenNumberGenerator()).toBeDivisbleByTwo();
    });
});
```

but when I run the page I get this error in internet explorer:

TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'toBeDivisbleByTwo'

is this due to the order of loading or something?

Comment: I don't know Jasmine well, but: your `beforeEach` is in a different suite from where you're using `toBeDivisibleByTwo`. Is that a problem? If you move your `beforeEach` out of its containing suite into top-level runner code, does that fix the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`beforeEach` functions only apply to the `it` functions within the `describe` which they are written and in any nested `describe` within that one. To solve your problem you can either nest your second `describe` inside your first or remove the second `describe` entirely and place your `it` inside the first one. It's up to you to decide how you want to organize your tests but in this case I recommend the second option because you have no `it` functions in the first `describe` as it is. Also, Jasmine syntax for `describe` and `it` is intended to read like plain English. So you can have something like...

```
describe('Even number generator', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
        //Your matcher
    });

    it('should return a number that is divisible by two', function() {
        expect(evenNumberGenerator()).toBeDivisbleByTwo();
    });
});
```

This helps organize and make sense of your tests.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Prolific library, that works along with Jasmine <2.0

https://github.com/Bitterbrown/prolific

(yes, I admit, I'm the developer :))
you can add your custom matcher, you'll find it on the readme file (I just updated it)

basically, after including prolific, you can do:

```
it("should be divisible by 2", function () {
  assume("var evenNumberGenerator() is divisible by 2");
})
```